# How much of the Mishnah is from Sinai?

Tags: mishna

I have been reading the Schottenstein edition of The Mishnah Elucidated and noticed that a lot of the Mishnayos turn out to be d'Rabbanan.

How much of the Mishnah is halachah l'moshe miSinai and how much is d'Rabbanan?

Comment: You want percentages? Exact amount of each?

Comment: @Chatzkel a rough idea would be a good start. Doesn't have to be too exact.

Comment: The Rambam in his introduction to Mishnayos counts 31 Halacha L’Moshe Misinai. There are a lot of things that are explanations of pesukim which were passed down from Moshe but are not called Halachos. Then there are gezeiros drabbanan. ואני אכלול בכאן רוב הדינין שנאמר בהן הלכה למשה מסיני ואפשר שיהיה הכל (ג) ויתבאר לך אמיתת מה שאמרתי https://www.sefaria.org/Rambam_Introduction_to_the_Mishnah.8.25?lang=bi

Comment: I would suggest that none is literally from Sinai, but the parts kept also by the Samaritans (as we don't have the Sadducees now) could shed some light on the earliest Halochos in existence.

Comment: Some claim that not Halochos were given to Moses, but the rules of extrapolating them from the scriptures.

Comment: @AlBerko are you sure the Samaritan mesorah would work? Karaites, for example, reject the Oral Law but use the same Shimonei Esrei we do...

Comment: @יהושעק IIRC, the Samaritans stem from the 1st Temple schism, while the Karaites came after the Talmud.

Comment: Note that AlBerko's views are contradicted by traditional Judaism. To say nothing in the Mishnah comes from Sinai denies the oral Torah.